# Using Stolen Device Protection to protect photos

Tags: iphone, ios, security

Is there a way to make photos viewable **only** using biometric access (face or touch ID)? The Hidden photo album and locked Notes are both accessible using a passcode, even with Stolen Device Protection activated.

Comment: iPad, iPhone, Mac, Apple Vision Pro? What platform are you asking about and what version of the operating system does it currently have?

Comment: @SteveChambers SDP is only available on the iOS 17.3, and the question is tagged “iPhone”.

Answer (score 2):

Stolen Device Protection only protects the key logins/passwords as defined by Apple (mainly your AppleID), it can’t be used to protect other data elements.